# System.IO.Path equivalent in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, filesystems

There are a lot of nice little functions in System.IO.Path like replacing a file extension, append to a path, getting a filename, getting a directory from a path in C#.  Is there an iOS equivalent or somewhat close API?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. Have a look at ["Working with Paths"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38) section in `NSString` reference.

To work with actual files you need to use `NSFileManager` class

Answer (score 1):

[NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) has a number of methods that allow you to manipulate paths.

It's not super elegant, but it's very useful.

```
NSString *textFile = @"readme.txt"
NSString *markdownFile = [[textFile stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"markdown"];

// markdownFile is now "readme.markdown"
```